# Reacting to Button commands inside a Web Usercontrol in a ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net, events, repeater, webusercontrol

I have an ASP.NET repeater, whose ItemTemplate is a WebUsercontrol named ProviderControl.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rep_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <custom:ProviderControl ID="row" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am populating the custom control with data in the `ItemDataBound` event.

Inside the provider control I have two buttons that I want to be able to react to on the containing Page.
I know there are Commands, and Command arguments, but how would I do that?

Or is there an easier way than using Commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle `ItemCommand` event of "Repeater".

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = e.CommandSource as Button;
        Response.Write(btn.ID);
    }
```

Comment: That would work if the Button is directly beneath the Repeater. However, in my case the Button again is inside of another control. Will the e.CommandSource find the correct Button control?

Comment: Thanks but the event is not handled at the Page level. I only added a COmmandName attribute to the button in my user control. Is that all I need to do? I configured the repeater in the page to fire the ItemCommand event. Anything else?

Comment: it works. Thanks again. Is the command mechanism a bubbling event by any chance? Like in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to provide custom events in your `UserControl` for each button-click event. The `UserControl` will raise and the page can handle them.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3